# PDF: understanding numbers in the array when using the TJ Operator

Tags: pdf

I'm trying to find out how you should use the numbers in an array of a TJ operator in a PDF file.

I'm using the example:

```
[(A)120(W)120(A)95(Y again)]TJ
```

How should the numbers be used?

1. Should they be handled individually?
2. Should the number be used with the string before it for the calculation of the first character of that string before it? e.g.: (A) + 120
3. Should the number be used with the string behind it for the calculation of the first character of that string behind it? e.g.: 120 + (W)
4. Other option?

So far I have been trying to handle it individually, but without good results.

Looking forward to reading your answers/comments to help understanding it better.
(Hopefully the other calculations for the combined displacement are correct).

Another example array:

```
[(1.1)-1753(A)1(bo)-7(ut This Book)]TJ
```

**update:**

sample file I test: http://www.filedropper.com/9mei2018reduced

"bad" result:

[image]

The array with strings and numbers for TJ:

```
[(1)-100(0)-99( )-101(m)-100(e)-100(i)-99( )-101(1)-100(9)-99(1)-100(8)
-99( )-101(d)-99(e)-100( )-101(r)-99(a)-101(i)-99(d)-100(s)-100( )-101(o)
-100(p)-100( )-100(O)-100(o)-100(s)-100(t)-100(e)-100(n)-100(d)-99(e)]TJ
```

When calculating Tx, I handle the strings and numbers separately. For the calculations of the numbers (-100, -99, -101,...) when I add a glyph width of 100 instead of 0 for the w0 parameter, the result is ok... but I can't keep this w0(100) value there for the numbers as 98% of other pdf files are wrong with this value..

Comment: Please elaborate on "without good results".For example, how do you know?

Comment: well good result = rendered text is the same as in foxit reader, adobe reader, etc... a bad result = text rendered on top or with spaces etc... (own renderer trying to fix the TJ operator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The equation

It looks like you attempt to interpret the equation

```
tx = ((w0 - Tj/1000) * Tfs + Tc + Tw) * Th
```

in glyph space instead of text space, at least the values you insert appear to indicate that. Instead interpret it in text space in a font-type agnostic manner.

In particular:

- `w0` - use the width of the respective character from the width array in the PDF font dictionary and divide it by 1000; I would expect a value of about .667 for the capital A.
- `Tj` - use the value from the **TJ** operation array parameter, e.g. 120.
- `Tfs` - use the font size from the graphics state which is the font size parameter from the relevant **Tf** operation, e.g. 10.
- `Tc` - use the value from the graphics state which is the parameter from the relevant **Tc** or **"** operation.
- `Tw` - use 0 or (in case of a single-byte character code 32) the value from the graphics state which is the parameter from the relevant **Tw** or **"** operation.
- `Th` - use the value from the graphics state which is the parameter from the relevant **Tz** operation divided by 100.

#### Your example file

Unfortunately you don't show the *x* coordinates your code calculated for the origins of the glyphs, so I cannot tell whether your calculations are wrong or something else in your code is.

As the values mostly are trivial (font size 1, no Tc or Tw, Th 1), I manually calculated the *x* coordinates of the glyph origins for the first few characters:

```
character   x coordinate
'1'         734.204784
'0'         745.564784
' '         756.908784
'm'         765.452784
'e'         779.468784
'i'         790.012784
' '         796.076784
'1'         804.620784
'9'         815.980784
'1'         827.324784
'8'         838.684784
' '         850.028784
'd'         858.572784
```

According to your image, your coordinates already are pretty wrong here.

The coordinates I calculated appear to be correct, though, they in particular match the coordinates of the vector graphics instructions drawing the 'shadows' of the glyphs.

Thus, please compare with the coordinates your code calculated. If yours differ, in particular if they differ increasingly, you still don't do the calculations as explained above, at least not accurately so (probably you use a numeric type that is too lossy in these calculations?). If yours don't differ, then your problem is not in the calculation of the coordinates but in their use; you in particular then use them differently for text then for vector graphics instructions.

Comment: To render "A " in the example. Does it mean you have to calculate the formule once (using w0(A) + TJ=120 in the formula). Or calculate the formula twice (first calculate using: w0(A) + TJ=0 and after that calculate using: w0() + TJ=120 ) ?

Comment: It depends on what you try to achieve. If you want to calculate the combined displacement to get from the origin of 'A' to the origin of 'W', you can calculate that in one step, i.e. for `w0` of the character 'A' and `Tj` of the value 120. If you somehow want to treat the back-step of 120 somehow special and need to know where you would be without it, you can apply the formula twice, once for 'A' with `Tj = 0` and once for 120 with `w0 = 0`.

Comment: most pdf files render correctly, but some are not ok. For example I calculate the displacements separately (see previous comment). When calculating a number from the array the spacing is incorrect. However when I set a glyphwidth of 100, the spacing is correctly, but I'm not even have a glyph at that point, because I calculate the number from the array. and if I keep this w0=100 in the space calculation my other PDF's (98%) are incorrect. Can't find why it works with a value of w0 = 100 in some rare cases.

Comment: Please share an example file to illustrate what you mean.

Comment: Thanks mkl my calculations seem to be correct now. The key was w0 / 1000 and this: "It looks like you attempt to interpret the equation in glyph space instead of text space". I was using some in glyph and some in text space and for some reason that was almost always correct, but not everytime. Now I can focus on other problems!

Comment: how would it work with hex strings? [ <001300130002> -3000 <00310054004B0049004B005000470047004E> ]TJ    first time I see this in TJ operator

Comment: *first time I see this in TJ operator* - There is no reason not to use hex encoded strings in **TJ** operations. And it's not that seldom actually. Please explain what your problem is with them. It shouldn't make a difference to your code whether it operates on a hex encoded string `001300130002` in angle brackets or a byte string with the bytes 0x00, 0x13, 0x00, 0x13, 0x00, 0x02 enclosed in round brackets.

Comment: the parts with hex strings have some extra spaces at start or between the words/chars. Trying to find the issue as the characters itself appear normally now, only the spacing is not correct in some cases. time for coffee :)